# Highlight element does not appear in screenshot?. Please

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, bdd

I'm trying to capture an element with Highlight by screenshot, but in Screenshot this element doesn't appear with Highlight. Anyone know the solution?. The highlight appears when I am capturing the text: automatests@gmail.com

See my code:

```
Utility.captureScreenShot(driver, "Verifica Nome_Email");
         WebElement taketext1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb\"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a/img"));
         Helper.highLightElement(driver, taketext1);
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gb\"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a/img")).click();
         Thread.sleep(2000);
         WebElement taketext= driver.findElement(By.className("gb_tb"));
         Helper.highLightElement(driver, taketext);
         Thread.sleep(2000);
         Utility.captureScreenShot(driver, "Verifica Nome_Email");
         String emailatual = taketext.getText();
         assertTrue(emailatual.contains("automatests@gmail.com")); 
         driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click();
         driver.close();
```

method
public class Helper {

```
public static void highLightElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element)
{
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
 
//js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'background: transparent; border: 2px solid red;');", element);
 js.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='2px solid red'", element);
try 
{
Thread.sleep(1000);
} 
catch (InterruptedException e) {
 
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} 
 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','border: solid 2px white');", element); 
 
}
```

}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqExF.jpg)

Comment: Please do not post the same question more than once: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62436889/3092298

Comment: The question is still valid, and I have the same issue but in *headless* mode. When I drive with the browser visible, the screenshots do indeed have the css modification. I also add a driver.sleep(250) before the shot but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the Robot class in java.awt package to capture screenshot. You can replace your highLightElement method with following code:

```
public static void highlightAndCapture(WebDriver driver, WebElement elem)
            throws IOException, HeadlessException, AWTException {
        if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
            // To highlight the element
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='2px solid red'", elem);
            // To capture screenshot
            BufferedImage image = new Robot()
                    .createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("screenshot.png"));
            // To remove border from highlighted element(Optional)
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.border = \"none\";", elem);
        }
    }
```